# chef Network Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I have created 3 ec2 instances on AWS running redhat 7

the ip address of server is 10.205.78.136
the hostname file on server is listed as ip-10-205-78-136.x.y.com

from my workstation i can ping the ip but not the hostname

if the chef_server_url in knife.rb is set to ip address than I can download the ssl cert sing knife ssl fetch, but doing knife ssl check fails with following error

```
ERROR: You are attempting to connect to:   '10.205.78.136'
ERROR: The server's certificate belongs to 'ip-10-205-78-136.x.y.com'
```

If i update the chef_server_url ip-10-205-78-136.x.y.com than knife ssl fetch does not work

Comment: `ip-10-205-78-136.x.y.com` is a private hostname, may be you can try public hostname? It looks like `ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: The aws account is visible only on the company network, hence we do not have a public ip or dns. Just private once

Comment: Activate the name resolution in your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because after the chef server installation, we do a reconfigure, i.e., `chef-server-ctl reconfigure`, which always generates ssl certificates with hostname details as `/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/ip-10-205-78-136.x.y.com.crt`.

And hence, it is not mapped to the ipaddress, i.e., `10.205.78.136` on which you want to access.

So, in order to fix that, you may like to add following entries in below file:-

`/etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb`

```
server_name = "10.205.78.136"
api_fqdn server_name
nginx['url'] = "https://#{server_name}"
nginx['server_name'] = server_name
lb['fqdn'] = server_name
bookshelf['vip'] = server_name
```

And then, run the `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` command again which will update/reconfigure/generate ssl certificates from hostname, i.e.,`10-205-78-136.x.y.com`, to ipaddress, i.e., `10.205.78.136`.

After that you may install and configure chef-manage.

https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html

Comment: Appears to be under `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb` in chef server 13.